# My Custom Exception is not thrown, instead the ArrayOutOfBoundsException Is thrown (JunitTest Error)

Tags: java, junit5

i have a Problem with my Custom Exception, i want to throw a Custom Exception when the entered row/col does not excist in my shelf[][] which only kind of works. The custom exception does get thrown when i compile my main (error message is printed)- even though the throw part in my Code is apparently never reached (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OY52.png) - but it also throws the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. So when i Junit test my method for throwing InvalidRow/ColumnException it fails because it throws the ArrayOutOfBoundsException.
How do i solve this problem so my Junit test `assertThrows(InvalidRowException.class,() -> shelf.addItem(3, 0, bottle));` doesnt catch the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but instead only my InvalidRowException?

This is my Exception Class:

```
public class InvalidRowException extends ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

public InvalidRowException(int wrongRow){
    super("passed Row " + wrongRow + " doesnt excist.");
}
```

}

This is my Method

```
public void addItem(int row, int coll, Product product) throws InvalidRowException, InvalidColumnException {
    if (row < 0 | row > shelf.length)
        throw new InvalidRowException(row);
    if (coll < 0 | coll > shelf[1].length)
        throw new InvalidColumnException(coll);
    try {

        if (!(product instanceof Placeable)) {
            throw new ProductNotPlaceableException(product);
        } else if (shelf[row][coll] != null) {
            System.out.println("Replacing product with serial " + shelf[row][coll].getSerialNumber()
                    + " by product with serial " + product.getSerialNumber());
            shelf[row][coll] = product;
        } else {
            shelf[row][coll] = product;
        }

    } catch (ProductNotPlaceableException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Throwing an exception instead of just preventing the exception condition in the first place isn't a good strategy. Use validation to prevent your users from triggering this type of condition. Use careful code review to prevent yourself from triggering the same. If you really want to suppress an exception and throw a different one, you have to catch it and throw the other exception, but in this case, you're masking a the real problem with more mechanics than you need.. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You throw exception for
row > shelf.length

You should check for row > shelf.length -1 as arrays are 0 based

Similarly for coll the correct check is coll> shelf[row].length-1